# Hide particular database in redshift cluster from certain users

Tags: amazon-redshift

Having multiple DB's in a redshift cluster,is there a way a set of users can only view particular DB in cluster and all other DB's are hidden to him.
Currently all users can view DB's in a cluster.

Comment: Please have a look at the following stackoverflow post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551200/hide-databases-in-amazon-redshift-cluster-from-certain-users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551200/hide-databases-in-amazon-redshift-cluster-from-certain-users)

Comment: That revokes the access from all the databases, my requirement is to have give a user access to only one DB and when he login's, user should only he DB see he has access to, irrespective of many DB's present on cluster. Thus, he should be able to view only one DB.

Comment: Is the database in a separate schema (or can you put it in a separate schema)? If so, you could use a [Schema path](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Schemas_and_tables.html) to limit what they can see.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein For one Redshift  6 nodes cluster, We have example 5 DB's (1,2,3,4,5) under each DB we have separate multiple schema. Eg: DB 1 has schema's(A,B,C) and DB 2 has schema's (D,E,F). For isolating things, we want to create USER, in such a way, if he is given access to DB1, when he logs in to this cluster through tool (Eg. Agintiy), he should be able to view only DB 1. Thus virtually for this USER other 4 DB's shouldn't exist on this cluster as he just views Database 1. Currently, each user is able to view all DB's that exist on cluster.How do we CREATE such USER.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is not possible.

The [privileges that can be granted in PostgreSQL 8](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-grant.html) (on which Redshift is based) are:

```
GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | RULE | REFERENCES | TRIGGER }
    [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON [ TABLE ] tablename [, ...]
    TO { username | GROUP groupname | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]

GRANT { { CREATE | TEMPORARY | TEMP } [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON DATABASE dbname [, ...]
    TO { username | GROUP groupname | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]

GRANT { EXECUTE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON FUNCTION funcname ([type, ...]) [, ...]
    TO { username | GROUP groupname | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]

GRANT { USAGE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON LANGUAGE langname [, ...]
    TO { username | GROUP groupname | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]

GRANT { { CREATE | USAGE } [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON SCHEMA schemaname [, ...]
    TO { username | GROUP groupname | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]

GRANT { CREATE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON TABLESPACE tablespacename [, ...]
    TO { username | GROUP groupname | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

At table level, there is no ability to control visibility.

The closest is at the **schema** level, where privileges can be granted on whether they can use a schema.

Comment: Agreed, read the same. But while using the Cluster for professional purposes, no one would like to expose other Clients DB on same cluster to some other client sharing the same cluster. Thus this is generic use case, where in work space, organisation would want isolation in visibility on DB level also from certain users. Is there any workaround in doing so, would appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The max that you can do is to revoke (or do not grant) usage on schema / access to table that you want to conceal.

The user would still be able to view the schema / table in the listing, all its attributes (primary keys, columns etc) but will not be able to view any data and that should suffice the data protection intended.